# How can I prevent images on the same line from moving to a different line when the screen is horizontally shrunk?

Tags: html, css

```css
#div {}

img {
  height: 200px;
}

#img1 {
  float: left;
}

#img2 {
  float: right;
}

#img3 {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="div">

  <img id="img1" src="https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/blue-mountains-famous-tourism-scenery-lijiang_1417-1143.jpg" alt="">

  <img id="img2" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/490411/pexels-photo-490411.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350" alt="">

  <img id="img3" src="https://previews.123rf.com/images/smileus/smileus1505/smileus150500016/40147459-colorful-sunset-scenery-in-rural-landscape-with-a-bench-and-a-path-in-the-foreground-gold-fields-and.jpg" alt="">

</div>
```

Currently, when you shrink the screen horizontally, the images start stacking vertically, which I don't want, I want them to all stay on the same horizontal line.

I'm looking how to do the following things:

1. Make an image disappear when it starts overlapping another image.
2. Make the images push to the right past the vertical scroll bar when the images start to overlapping.

The reason I ask for both is because I've now got two projects where each require one of those two and I don't know how to do it :P

I'd also like to avoid @media only screen and (max-width: ---px) if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add separate div for each image, and arrange it by `display: flex` element. Also use `margin` for align contents inside the `flex` div.

```css
#div {
  display: flex;
}

.new {
  max-height: 200px;
}

.left {
  margin-right: auto;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 200px;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
.hidden-xs {
  display:none;
}
}
```

```html
<div id="div">

  <div class="new left">
    <img id="img1" src="https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/blue-mountains-famous-tourism-scenery-lijiang_1417-1143.jpg" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="new hidden-xs">
    <img id="img2" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/490411/pexels-photo-490411.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="new">
    <img id="img3" src="https://previews.123rf.com/images/smileus/smileus1505/smileus150500016/40147459-colorful-sunset-scenery-in-rural-landscape-with-a-bench-and-a-path-in-the-foreground-gold-fields-and.jpg" alt="">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: THANK YOU! One question though, how can I make the images disappear or go off-screen, instead of shrinking, when the window is shrunk?

Comment: you must use @media(max-width:..) in CSS

Comment: I see, I must cave into that haha, time to learn... thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```css
#div::after {
  display: table;
  content: "";
  clear: both;
}

#div img {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="demonstration.css" type="text/css">
  <title>Demo</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="div">

    <img id="img1" src="https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/blue-mountains-famous-tourism-scenery-lijiang_1417-1143.jpg" alt="">

    <img id="img2" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/490411/pexels-photo-490411.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350" alt="">

    <img id="img3" src="https://previews.123rf.com/images/smileus/smileus1505/smileus150500016/40147459-colorful-sunset-scenery-in-rural-landscape-with-a-bench-and-a-path-in-the-foreground-gold-fields-and.jpg" alt="">

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I need the elements (in this case the images) to have a fixed height, and I'd also like them not touching unless mandatory (e.g. screen shrinkage).

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code::

```css
    ul.img {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      white-space: nowrap;
      width: 500px;
      overflow-x: auto;
    }
    
    ul.img li {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="demonstration.css" type="text/css">
        
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <ul class="img">
      <!-- Inline styles added for demonstration purposes only. -->
      <li style="background-color: #000"></li>
      <li style="background-color: #cdc"></li>
      <li style="background-color: #fed"></li>
    </ul>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code, And modify your image height according to need.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="demonstration.css" type="text/css">
  <title>Demo</title>
  <style>
    #div {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    #div img{
        width: 33.33%;
        height: 200px;
    }

  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="div">

    <img id="img1" src="https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/blue-mountains-famous-tourism-scenery-lijiang_1417-1143.jpg" alt="">

    <img id="img2" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/490411/pexels-photo-490411.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350" alt="">

    <img id="img3" src="https://previews.123rf.com/images/smileus/smileus1505/smileus150500016/40147459-colorful-sunset-scenery-in-rural-landscape-with-a-bench-and-a-path-in-the-foreground-gold-fields-and.jpg" alt="">

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using a float for positioning.

Floats will automatically move to a new line when their containers becomes too small.

You could either set the size of the image container to a width of 600px with no resize in which your images would remain in place when the window becomes smaller.

Or you could use the fixed position which is what I would go for.

```
    #img1  {
        position: fixed;
        width:200px;
        left: 0px;
        top: 0px;
        border: 0px;
        padding: 0px;}
    #img2 {
        position: fixed;
        width:200px;
        left: 200px;
        top: 0px;
        border:0px;
        padding: 0px;}
    #img3 {
        position: fixed;
        width:200px;
        left: 400px;
        top: 0px;
        border: 0px;
        padding: 0px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont care about image resize, set the div with a minimum width of a total px sum of the image widths. That way you have less containers.